# Magento 1.9.3 custom controller 404 error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm developing a custom `admin` module for `magento` v1.9.3

Here is my module components :

-- **app/code/community/Jason/Module**

--- **etc**

---- config.xml

-- **controllers**

--- JasonModuleController.php

--- SettingsController.php

-- **app/etc/modules**

--- Jason_Module.xml

`app/etc/modules/Jason_Module.xml`:

```
<config>
 <modules>
  <Jason_Module>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </Jason_Module>
 </modules>
 <admin>
  <routers>
   <adminhtml>
    <args>
     <modules>
      <Jason_Modulebefore="Mage_Adminhtml">Jason_Module</Jason_Module>
     </modules>
    </args>
   </adminhtml>
  </routers>
 </admin>
</config>
```

`SettingsController.php` :

```
 class Jason_Module_SettingsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{        
    public function indexAction(){
        echo 2123322332;
    }
 }
```

**The problem is** when i try enter this url :
`http://..../admin/jasonmodule/settings` or `http://..../admin/jasonmodule/settings/index` it redirects me to 404 page not found !..

but of i replaced the url by any method from the other method action from the controller `JasonModuleController.php` then it works ? whats the problem ?

Comment: Try entering `http://..../admin/settings/index` only. Since you are hooking into `admin` prefix you are loosing the module prefix and `jasonmodule` is not needed. Alternatively you can create `Jason_Module_JasonmoduleController` with `settingsAction()` and this should work for your url.

Comment: Got it , thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

For admin section the directory structure should be

-- **controllers**

--- **Adminhtml**

---- SettingsController.php

And class name should be **Jason_Module_Adminhtml_SettingsController**

Also please add a space between **Jason_Module** and **before**.

```
<Jason_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Jason_Module</Jason_Module>
```

Comment: I tried but same , also i think when i set `<Jason_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Jason_Module</Jason_Module>` , then no need to put the controllers in `Adminhtml` folder or i have to append `_Adminhtml` to the config ... the only controller which its methods are working normally is `JasonModuleController.php` , but the other controllers no !..